# Improving current JavaScript map() call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following JS and while I was able to get it to work, it wasn't optimal as I needed to add a couple of `eslist-disable-next-line` to get it run.

I'm doing the following:

- Merging to arrays into 1
- Checking against an array of strings
- If any item in this new merged array matches one of them names, I then push that value into a new array and return that.

  ```
  const array1 = firstList;
  const array2 = secondList;

  const flatArray = [...array1, ...array2];

  const popularChoices = [
       'All Items',
       'First item',
       'Another item',
       'Something else',
       'This/one',
       'blah'
  ];

  // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
  let updatedArray = [];

  // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
  flatArray.map((specialty) => {
      if (popularChoices.includes(specialty.name)) {
         updatedArray.push(specialty);
      }
  });

  return updatedArray;
  ```

Ideally I would be returning the map function itself, but I'm not sure how close I am to actually doing that correctly.

Any tips/notes would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: `map` is for when you want a value for each item in the collection. `filter` is for when you want **some** of them *(seems to be the case?)* A `Set` might be better than a ton of `includes` loops  *(but for small arrays `includes` isn't that bad)*.

Comment: You shouldn't need to disable ES Lint for `updatedArray`; that reference is not modified *(`push` just pushes)*.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks!  I'll look into that, I tend to mix them up quite a bit I feel.

Comment: Do you need a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) here? You can trivially union or exclude on those.

Comment: @DaveNewton for set, is this what you mean (I haven't used this yet): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set

Comment: The ES Lint warning is because you ignore `map`'s return value; a `forEach` would make more sense if you don't need the new array--but `filter` is what you actually want.

Comment: Stop disabling lint rules. The linter is trying to tell your the same things as the people commenting here. You don't need `let` and you shouldn't use `.map` for side-effects. If you don't understand a particular lint rule or why you're seeing an error, *that* is potentially a good question for stack overflow (although make sure to search first!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DaveNewton and @tadman thank you the details and Set reference.

Here is the updated code without ES Lint errors. Thanks again!

```
const popularChoices = new Set([
    'value',
    'etc',
    ...
]);

const updatedArray = flatArray.filter((specialty) => {
    let result = false;
    if (popularChoices.has(specialty.name)) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
});
```